# Synchonous Vs Asynchronous Calling in iOS App

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, synchronous

At Apple's site, they say:
**"Because this call can potentially take several minutes to fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application."**

In my case, the Application has nothing (**literally nothing**), to do in between the calling of WebService and the response returned. (There is **no other activity** My Application can Perform in between **as per Specifications**).

What should I do?

Is there any reason, (as per the situation) that can convince -- I should go for Asynchronous Call to WebService.

Any suggestions, as I am not very familiar to it ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always go for asynchronous calls - otherwise you freeze whole UI of your app, due to blocking the main thread.

In other words: user will have his phone blocked when the request will be processed.

Comment: Can't I use ActivityIndicatorView during that time period?

Comment: This has nothing to do with any particular view - you just block rendering of your UI. If your app will be in this state for too long, system will issue warnings and finally kill your app for being unresponsive.

Comment: But What if the nextView (to be loaded),is created based on response to the call. I mean, Async call loads the nextview immediately (all blank).What should i do then(other than reloading the view again)?

Comment: Create your nextView when you get response from your asynchronous call. It's particularly useful, when you use ASIHTTPRequest with blocks, see: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_blocks from ASIHTTPRequest library.

Comment: You wrote "In other words: user will have his phone blocked when the request will be processed." -- Is it so?? Or just my UI of my App will go blocked? and Also I don't want to use other FrameWork for it.

Comment: @codeCube You can't use ActivityIndicatorView during that time because the UI is locked. (Depending on how you do it, the best case is that it appears but doesn't animate.)

Comment: Worth noting: you can use synchronous requests with NSOperation or Grand Central Dispatch. Still, the whole point is not to block the UI thread.